# unable to create view

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting error : View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter  with the query below.How do I create view for the same.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

Comment: Have you declared the variable "@rownum"??

Comment: (SELECT @rownum := 0) t this is where it happens right. the query works fine without view statement but not with it.

Comment: I think `:=` used in `Delphi`. Is it correct in `mySql` too?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @rownum int

CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @rownum int CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
CREATE VIEW V AS 
(
SELECT (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*) FROM uservotes where votes < T.votes ) AS NUM, name, votes 
FROM uservotes T ORDER BY votes DESC
)
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46048/2)

You can define a variable in order to get psuedo row number functionality, because MySQL doesn't have any ranking functions:

### Can't Use A Variable in a MySQL View

If you do, you'll get the 1351 error, because [you can't use a variable in a view due to design](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).  The [bug/feature behavior is documented here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26140).